# Help with 閲覧できるの投稿

Tags: particle-の

In [this](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20230705/amp/k10014119301000.html) nhk article about the recent twitter restrictions, I came across this passage:

> **閲覧できるの投稿**の数は1日あたり、▽認証済みアカウントでは6000件、 ▽認証されていないアカウントは600件、 ▽作成されたばかりの認証されていないアカウントは300件までとしました。

I'm not aware of this kind of verbのnoun pattern being grammatical, so I can't really imagine why the choice was made to insert a の here when it didn't seem necessary.

My best guess is that it's making a nominalised topic out of 閲覧できる, with a pause implied after it, meaning something like: "As for what one can browse, the number of posts per day is..."

Comment: It's a mere typo. の must not be there.

Comment: I have an impression that this unnecessary の is often used by Chinese speakers due to (difference between Japanese の and) their use of 的.